# Populating a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I can't wrap my head around what's missing in my function to populate a binary tree vs the manual input.
Printing the head value along with its left & right node value doesn't seem to help me as well since it looks correct to me. However, printing out all the values after auto populating it produces a strange result.

The values of this binary tree will be coming from an array:

```
std::vector<ValueType> values = {
       3,
      7,4,
     2,4,6,
    8,5,9,3
};
```

Here is the tree relation:

```
         3
       (7,4)
     7        4
   (2,4)    (4,6)
  2       4       6
(8,5)   (5,9)   (9,3)
```

As you can see, the parent node is located above and its children is below enclosed in parenthesis.

```
row1: the root node 3 have left:7, right:4
row2: parent 7 have left:2, right:4
row2: parent 4 have left:4, right:6
...
```

This may seem not be a binary tree as mentioned from the comments, but look at it as a tree having null left or right node or a node having a shared children from its sibling (same row).

Below is the function to automatically populate the binary tree:

```
// ValueType is defined as an alias of int
void populateTree(BinaryTree* node, int rowCount, int lastIndex, std::vector<ValueType> values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {
        iterCount++;
        int currentRow = (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
        int x = i + 1;
        int nextRow = (x * (x + 1)) / 2;
        bool toggle = false;
        for (int j = nextRow; j < nextRow + x; ++j) {
            auto value = values[currentRow++];
            node->value = node->parent != nullptr ? value : node->value;

            if (j >= values.size())
                continue;

            auto leftValue = values[j + 0];
            auto rightValue = values[j + 1];
            node->left = new BinaryTree(node, leftValue);
            node->right = new BinaryTree(node, rightValue);

            if (j != currentRow)
                std::cout << ", ";

            std::cout << node->value << "(" << node->left->value << "," << node->right->value << ")";

            node = toggle ? node->right : node->left;
            toggle = !toggle;
        }
        
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have used the [triangular number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula) to map the array into row and column.

Now, to confirm if the code is working, starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom should be 23.

I've done this by traversing bottom-up and add all the adjacent node combinations. Here's the output of the result:

```
3(7,4)
7(2,4), 4(4,6)
2(8,5), 4(5,9), 6(9,3)

iter count: 14
============
[4, 4, 7, 3]:18
[5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3]:25
[3, 6, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3]:29
[3, 6, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3]:29
[5, 2, 4, 7, 3]:21
[4, 7, 3]:14
[4, 3]:7
pair total sum: 54
```

There supposed to be a combinations of `[n1, n2, n3, ...nX]:23`.

However, if I build the binary tree manually, there is a correct combination:

```
3(7,4)
7(2,4), 4(4,6)
2(8,5), 4(5,9), 6(9,3)

iter count: 14
============
[8, 2, 7, 3]:20
[5, 2, 7, 3]:17
[5, 4, 7, 3]:19
[9, 4, 7, 3]:23 <--- this is the correct combination.
[5, 4, 4, 3]:16
[9, 4, 4, 3]:20
[9, 6, 4, 3]:22
[3, 6, 4, 3]:16
pair total sum: 83
```

Link to full source code: https://gist.github.com/mr5z/8249a9101e5bfdce4850602c3ea7ebf3

This is part of my solution to [project euler#18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values to see when and where something doesn't happen as you expected it to?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've reduced the link to source code to 151 lines. Is that enough?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes. I always use a debugger. It's just hard for me to grasp what am I missing with the code rather than what values I missed to expect to see in the debugger.

Comment: no. A link to source code on some external site is not enough. Questions should be selfcontained, ie everything needed included in the question. Links and images can be used to support the question, but they should be avoided for essential information

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm sorry. I have reduced the LoC to 125. As far as I can tell, all the codes from that level is essential to my question. Would copy-pasting all the codes from gist to here make my question valid to you?

Comment: i personally would rather have the code than the screenshots included. The screenshots take lots of space while their content could be posted as text. Formalisms aside, I dont understand what is the difference between "I've done this by traversing bottom-up and add all the adjacent node combinations" and "I build the binary tree manually" and I also cannot find this in the code

Comment: @idclev463035818 sure. I will convert the images into texts. I didn't include the source code of the tree traversal in my question. Do you think it would be good to include it as well?

Comment: One basic thing I see is that while you call this a binary tree, it isn't. If I understand your output correct, the node with value 4 from the third line is a child of *both* nodes from the second line. Meaning that this is not even a tree. And if you create input like this, it pretty much *has* to be ambiguous in regards to building a valid binary tree if a line does not exactly have two times the amount of nodes than the line before.

Comment: TL;DR. Stopped at the first snippet: please explain, whose child should the second `4` be, and who would be children of the first `4`.

Comment: @Aziuth this is a question from [project euler#18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) (will mention in the post as well). Yes. You could also look at it like a merged node. I thought the arrangement of the data fits to a binary tree that's why I have migrate the data from array to binary tree. While there is no exactly two left & right nodes for every parent node, I still think it is a valid tree.

Comment: @CiaPan I have added some details explaining how each nodes relates to each other.

Comment: The _first sentence_ of the wikipedia page on [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) says _"... each node has at most two children,"_ and Project Euler just describes it as a triangle.

Comment: @Useless ah yes. I have reworded my question. Every parent nodes here have a left and right children.

Comment: Use appropriate names for things to communicate properly with other people (and to understand sources, either printed or published in the Web). Nodes having 'shared children' make the whole structure **not a tree**. It's a case of [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), but not a tree. A [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) requires each node to be referenced at most once, that is to be a child of exactly one parent (except the root node, which has no parent).

Comment: @mr5 Trees can literally be defined as cycle-free graphs. That said, if you identify trees as data structures rather than mathematic definitions, it might work, but I'd be very cautious about how they are implemented. Your code implies that there are raw pointers, and thus my question would be, when is a node deleted? How is double deletion avoided? If it had smart pointers, I'd be less cautious but still be. In any case, I'd consider it to be badly named, if it is called tree despite not being one. Maybe Pyramid? GaltonBoard? Lattice? Depends on the context I guess.

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for pointing it out. I was thinking also to name the data structure as graph but I got stuck to name it as binary tree without thinking too much. As for the "referenced" child, in the programming context, there is really no children that have been referenced twice, it only get copied by value. I am picturing it out as a pyramid of values wherein the duplicate values have been merge into one instead, but it could also be written as a balanced binary tree.

Comment: OK, you claim the problem is in how you _build_ your triangle, because some other algorithm not included in the question gives the wrong result. But it looks like you also run a different algorithm, right? The "bad" output is sort-of top-down, but sometimes misses the root node? Why are you running different tests, and assuming the problem is with the setup?

Comment: @mr5 I just read through the problem you are trying to solve, and I'd recommend leaving it be a two-dimensional array. You don't need a pointer structure. Especially for the dynamic programming approach you are going to take I'd find it easier to store the additional information in another two-dimensional array, allowing indices to correspond. The other way would be to store that additional information (sub-problem solution and backtracking information) directly in the nodes, but that is mixing up input and solution.

Comment: @Useless the algorithm to test if it's correct is the same. The only difference from two test are the way how I build the "triangle" structure. I didn't include the code for testing it because I thought it just adds more noise to my question. There is a link of the full source code in my post.

Comment: So they both print out the same (above the row of `===`), but the traversal is different? That means your `printNodes` is doing something wrong (ie, discarding some of the node structure), and you should work on accurately visualizing what you really built first

Comment: @Useless no. I have included the manual way to build the "triangle" as a comment (was part of it before because somebody told me to reduce it). If you have time, you can comment out the `populateTree` and replace it with the manual tree builder instead.

Comment: But the triangle you build is the same _type_ of structure of node pointers, and the output you show is from the same `printNodes` function? Because if it prints the same and behaves differently, you must be losing information when you print it.

Comment: Re [_I am picturing it out as a pyramid of values (...) but it could also be written as a balanced binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005625/populating-a-binary-tree?noredirect=1#comment113184335_64005625). NO, that should not be written as a balanced binary tree. A pyramid with 100 rows has 100*(100+1)/2 = 5050 elements, while a complete binary tree of 100 levels has over a nonillion nodes: 2^100-1 = 1 267650 600228 229401 496703 205375. Are you sure you want to allocate them...?!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure about why your implement a tree structure an your own, but if your goal is visualisation of a certain tree structure: I would suggest you to use the [boost cpp graph library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) in combination with [graphiz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
See an [example here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/graph/example/family-tree-eg.cpp), which shows the construction of a family tree, in a more "graph orientated" way. Every graph (like a tree) has nodes and edges.

If you want to train your programming skills, please go ahead: I found the following example for a [b-tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-b-tree) quite useful in my past.
Couldn’t you use a “normal” insertIntoTree function instead of you populateTree function ? Or is this a matter of performance for you ?

Answer (score 0):

What you do here is an example of an XY problem (see here: [Meta StackExchange: What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or there: [GreyCat's Wiki: XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)) – you're trying to put your data into a tree structure just because they are presented in a way resembling a tree-like pyramid, but you did not check if such structure will actually help you solve the problem.

And the answer is: NO, it will not; it doesn't even fit the actual problem structure.

Your problem structure is a pyramid-like triangle of integer numbers, each of which has two nearest descendants (except those in the bottom row) and two nearest ancestors (except those on side edges, which have just one ancestor, and the top item, which has no ancestors at all). And you have already mapped that structure into a linear array by your 'triangular formula':

> given a row number `r` in a range of `0 .. N-1` and a position in the row `p` in a range of `0 .. r` and an array with indices `0 .. N*(N+1)/2-1`,
> the item `(r,p)` is stored in the array at index `r*(r+1)/2 + p`,
> and its 'children' are `(r+1,p)` and `(r+1,p+1)`.

That's all, the mapping allows you to access data in a 'triangular' manner, you need no tree to handle it.